# how to press back button programmatically in android

Tags: android, button, android-service, android-hardware

A **SERVICE I HAVE NOT ANY ACTIVITY** is running in forebackground and when user click on app button i want do function of hardware back button
`onBackPressed` is not working inside service!!
[image]

Comment: onClick() handler of the button, use super.onBackPressed() to go back to preivous activity

Comment: :DDDD I CANT SPEAK ENGLISH WELL

Answer (score 4):

**Is it not possible to programmatically press the back button on android through a service**

> [**onBackPressed()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
>   Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.

you need to just call `onBackPressed()`  method
 don't forgot override `onBackPressed()` in your activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();   
        // perform your action here

    }
```

Comment: @dornadev **Is it not possible to programmatically press the back button on android through a service**

Comment: I DEVELOPED HOME BUTTON AND RECENT BUTTON JUST NEED TO BACK BUTTON

Comment: explain in brief @dornadev **I DEVELOPED HOME BUTTON AND RECENT BUTTON JUST NEED TO BACK BUTTON**

Comment: OP has a `Service`. He wants to press the BACK button programatically. He doesn't have an `Activity` running, so can't call any methods of `Activity`. This answer is not relevant.

Comment: @DavidWasser i know that read first line of my ans **Is it not possible to programmatically press the back button on android through a service**

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's not possible to press "BACK" from service.
Since you don't have an activity in the foreground, you don't have the ability to programmatic to press a BACK press, due the fact the service not provide any user interface.
What is the option - If you have a rooted device with an access to shell you can try to use the following command in the service 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 4");

Comment: Good idea, I'm trying it but if used in an activity it works, while in a service (floating window) it doesn't do anything, do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle back button operation  like this;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// your code.
}
```

otherwise try below code;

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // your code
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to detect the BACK button being pressed. He wants to press it himself programatically. This answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle back button operation like this;

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //Home Button!
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to detect the BACK button being pressed. He wants to press it himself programatically. This answer is not relevant.